# Importação de Dados PDF em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Pode ser uma pergunta meio besta, mas ainda assim preciso fazer:

É possível importar os dados de um arquivo em `pdf` no `php` e salvar em banco `mysql`?

Comment: Sim é possível! não dizer exatamente sem detalhes se é com muito ou pouco trabalho.

Comment: Se der é beeeem trabalhoso...

Comment: Bom dia, Alguém sabe me dizer como ?

Att,

Comment: Da forma como você quer saber, parece que a resolução é ampla e complexa demais, o que foge o escopo do site(viraria mais um tutorial).

Comment: Não precisa ser um tuto e sim um inicio ou ate mesmo link,o qual documentação seria,ou seja um pontapé inicial,pois não encontrei nada direto.

Comment: Acredito que não precisa ser um tutorial. Acho que uma resposta bem completa de quem possa ajudar já seria o bastante. É uma boa pergunta e pode ajudar quem também quer saber como fazer isso.

Comment: Já respondendo a segunda e mais fácil parte da pergunta, se você importar os dados do arquivo pdf, você conseguirá salvar no banco. Agora a parte difícil da sua pergunta não sei como. Acredito que terá alguém aqui que poderá ajudar.

Comment: [Read pdf files with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1004478/1342547)

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa library http://www.pdfparser.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma bem legal e interessante é usar esse projeto do Git:

https://github.com/angeloskath/Pdf-to-text-via-PHP

```
<?php
include ('../pdf.php');
if ($argc<2)
{
    echo "\n\tphp -f pdf2text.php filename.pdf\n\n";
    die;
}
$pdf = new Pdf($argv[1]);
foreach ($pdf->getStreams() as $obj)
{
    echo $obj->getValue()->toString();
}
?>
```

depois vc usa o foreach para realizar os devidos inserts no banco :)

Comment: Isso é feito via linha de comando certo?

Comment: Ok,muito obrigado.

Comment: @OtacioBarbosa, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Isso é um exemplo que já consta na documentação

Comment: Deivison Francisco, ta dando sim,era exatamente o que estava proucurando,após pronto mostro a documentação. Obrigado pela informação.